# does linux kill() return after the process excute signal handler?

Tags: linux, signals, glibc

I want use kill() to kill a program.
does linux kernel ensure that the program is killed before kill() returned?
If not, I have to check whether the program is killed already.

Comment: `kill()` returns after the kernel knows to send the requested signal to the given process or process group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *does linux kernel ensure that the program is killed before kill() returned?*

No, `kill` merely [sends a signal to a process or group of processes](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html).  Its successful return only tells you that the signal was sent.

The Linux man pages are straightforward about this, clarifying that a successful return means [*"at least one signal was sent"*](https://linux.die.net/man/2/kill).

So, this does not tell you whether the signal is blocked/held pending by the target process, was ignored (SIG_IGN), has taken its default action, has been handled, or accepted.